# Adding input dynamically and using .mask is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project I use Bootstrap 4 and jQuery / JavaScript.

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.currencyMask').mask("###0.00", {reverse: true});
    $('.numbersMask').mask("#", {reverse: true});
});

function getDynamicInput(productType) {
    $(".dynamic-content-input").load("{{ route('product.product.feature') }}/" +
                                         productType +
                                         "/@if (!empty($product)){{ $product->id }} @else{{0}} @endif",
                                     function (response, status, xhr) {
    });
}
```

This code in result dynamic input:

```
<div class="dynamic-content-input">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-form-label text-right col-lg-3 col-sm-12">Pole liczbowe</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" name="form-2" class="form-control  numbersMask " value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-form-label text-right col-lg-3 col-sm-12">Pole tekstowe</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" name="form-3" class="form-control " value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This work fine. Problem is with the JavaScript function *numbersMask*.

When I add input in HTML - it's working fine (the function allows you to enter only numbers).

However, for input dynamically added, it does not work at all.

How can I repair it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code `.mask` code to this below. It should work for your dynamic inputs as well.

The reason it's not working is that when the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) is loaded those dynamic inputs are not available to be masked with your requirements.

So in this case we need to use *event binding* in jQuery and use the jQuery `.on` method. The way it works is that it checks the whole document and applies your `.mask` to you input, including dynamically loaded inputs.

In your case, we will just need call the mask when you *click* or *focus* on the elements.

```
$(document).on("focus", ".currencyMask", function() {
  $(this).mask("###0.00", {
    reverse: true
  });
});

$(document).on("focus", ".numbersMask", function() {
  $(this).mask("#", {
    reverse: true
  });
});
```